# Get all youtube links shared by current user's facebook friends from the past hour

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all youtube links shared by current user's facebook friends from the past hour.

I have found an FQL script that would get the latest 100 links shared by the current user's friends but I am trying to query only for youtube links and for the past hour instead of a limit of 100.

This is the script that I have found. How can I change it?

select link_id, title, url, owner, owner_comment, created_time, picture from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 100) ORDER BY created_time DESC

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a limitation of the Facebook API.  Was there any pagination information in your response that would allow you to page thru the results?

Comment: To help preserve overall application responsiveness an application can choose to impose upper limits as to *how much* information to process and send in one request's response.  This is where pagination comes into play.  The API is kind enough to give you next/previous links to access the next virtual page of information.